# Close session in tab when user log in with different credentials in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am working on a online credit card's web site and need to include a kind of single session per browser feature.

Examinating different Home Banking systems I found the requested behaviour in all of them. However, I didn´t find the mechanism to do it myself. What I need to do is the following:

1. User opens a browser tab and goes to http://thecreditcardsite.com
2. User log in with his credentials and gets access to the site content
3. User opens a new tab and goes to http://thecreditcardsite.com (now there are two opened tabs)
4. User log in with different credentials in the new tab
5. User see that the first tab changed and the login page is displayed.

This seems to be a very common behavior in this kind of applications (credit card, online banking systems), how can I do that?

Comment: When on login you find the info in your session that the user is already logged in – then destroy the session, and start a new one …

Comment: Of course, that can be done server side. However, that I can see, and the customer wants, is a client-side behavior: when you login on the second tab the first tab is redirected to logout page (or login page or other type of page)

Comment: Well, then the first tab has to _query_ for whether it’s session is still valid (polling), or to be _notified_ (postMessage).

Comment: Yes, my question seems to be incomplete. That was the first thing that I did. Using Fiddle2 I didn´t see any request to the server. It is like a kind of inter tab communication. Can that be possible?

Comment: Yes. And I already mentioned a way of doing that …